# Detect when facebook loads more posts - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am working with a chrome extension. Through this extension I am adding another **Private Like** button on each of the posts. After searching I have found the CSS class of the tab where the like, share and comment buttons exists on each post. So right on that tab I want to append my extra private like button, which is basically can done by an extension. I have made a button and even appended it in that tab, but the problem is, the button is added to those posts which are already posted. When I scroll down the page and more posts are loaded then my private like button doesn't appear. So, the solution is to detect when Facebook loads more posts, and it appends the button to the new posts.

Simply, How would I detect if Facebook has loaded new posts to the same page.

**Script to Append the button**

```js
var fbEl = $("._42nr");
var btn = '<div style="float:left;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;height:14px;color:#4b4f56;padding-right:27px;line-height:34px;" class="myprivateLikeButton"><img src="http://bitbaysolutions.com/Icons/icon_like.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;margin-right:7px;float:left;margin-top:8px;">Private Like</div>"';
$(btn).appendTo(fbEl);
```

Comment: You would need to constantly poll the page, and check for the number of `fbEl` on the page.

Comment: So you mean I have to check if the number o fbEl get greater than the current one then I have to call that function